# Crosstab with additional column

Tags: crystal-reports

My report needs a normal cross-tab section, but with an additional pre-computed column (It's the average of all the non-zero weeks of activity, so a normal cross-tab average will not work). This is a column that is supplied in my dataset.

How can I get it to look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a SQL Command to your report in the Database Expert?

[image]

If you perform the pre-calculations in SQL and pass the results in as a Command table, you can use the calculations like regular table fields. These can be used in a Crosstab like normal fields.

Comment: I have not done this before, so it might be the answer, but I'm not sure. I have these values already computed in my dataset, so I don't think I need to compute anything. I believe my challenge is to incorporate a pre-computed column into the cross-tab section when it doesn't have a week-ending date associated with it (which is the value that indicates which column values should appear in). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: It's difficult to understand the structure you're describing, but you can use this Add Command to retrieve existing data. Then it's a matter of linking the tables in Crystal. (Not on `week-ending date`, as you mentioned: You will need to use something else as a link.)

Comment: The data set is structured like this: every record has a week-ending date, a route number, a revenue value, and a route average (which is a pre-computed average of all the non-zero revenue values for the route). My challenge is that when I use the cross-tab, I can't figure out a way to include this route average value. I need another column which can contain the average values and appears next to the Route. It is not really part of the crosstab, but needs to be inserted into it somehow. Thanks for your input so far. Any more ideas?

Comment: @TedK Your crosstab is populated `whilereadingrecords`, so info in a crosstab needs to be calculated before the printing phase - By having the calculations already done in the SQL statement, you can beat it to the punch, and can therefore insert them as a column.

Comment: This sounds very promising. I'm new to some of this stuff. Can you give a hint on how to access 'whilereadingrecords'. This input has been very helpful.

Comment: @TedK Use https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic737.html